# Is it possible to combine two arrays within an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that has some data that looks like this

```
$valueOptions = array(
                       'order_shipping_data_firstname' => Mage::helper('orders2csv')->__('order shipping firstname'), 
                       'order_shipping_data_lastname' => Mage::helper('orders2csv')->__('order shipping lastname'),
                       'order_shipping_data_region' => Mage::helper('orders2csv')->__('order shipping region'),
                       'order_shipping_data_street' => Mage::helper('orders2csv')->__('order shipping street'),
                       'order_shipping_data_city' => Mage::helper('orders2csv')->__('order shipping city')
                );
```

I need to combine the firstname and last name fields but can't figure out a solution. This is the only file in the module that references anything lastname / first name / name so it's calling it externally from within the magento framework. Ideally they would be stored in variables and I could just combine them $fullname = $first . $last etc but this won't work in arrays.

I don't understand the usage of `=>` too well but I know if I edit the right hand side and make this : `=> Mage::helper('orders2csv')->__('order shipping fullname')` the option will appear where I want (in a dropdown), so I guess I'm trying to combine `'order_shipping_data_firstname'&'order_shipping_data_lastname'` and put it before this,  but within the array?

I've also tried starting another array in a variable and inserting the variable in the valueOptions array but this broke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$foo = array(
    'bar' => array(
        "hello",
        "world"
    ),
);
var_dump($foo);
```

array nested in array

Comment: Could you give me an example of how this would be applicable in my example. It seems that the Mage::helper('orders2csv')->__('order shipping street') part renders the dropdown menu - so I think I am trying to join the  'order_shipping_data_firstname' and 'order_shipping_data_lastname' party then Mage::helper('orders2csv')->__('order shipping fullname'),

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$orders = Mage::helper('orders2csv');
$valueOptions = array(
        'order_shipping_data_firstname' => $orders->__('order shipping firstname'), 
        'order_shipping_data_lastname' => $orders->__('order shipping lastname'),
        'order_shipping_data_fullname' => $orders->__('order shipping firstname').' '.$orders->__('order shipping lastname'),
        'order_shipping_data_region' => $orders->__('order shipping region'),
        'order_shipping_data_street' => $orders->__('order shipping street'),
        'order_shipping_data_city' => $orders->__('order shipping city')
);
```

Or this:

```
$orders = Mage::helper('orders2csv');
$valueOptions = array(
        'order_shipping_data_firstname' => $orders->__('order shipping firstname'), 
        'order_shipping_data_lastname' => $orders->__('order shipping lastname'),
        'order_shipping_data_fullname' => $orders->__('order shipping fullname'),
        'order_shipping_data_region' => $orders->__('order shipping region'),
        'order_shipping_data_street' => $orders->__('order shipping street'),
        'order_shipping_data_city' => $orders->__('order shipping city')
);
```